# Meteor streaming data without persistancy: Asking for best / right practise

Tags: meteor

I just want to monitor or handle interactions with "things" that send out some data and are listening for actions.

For an example to send a pulse read or generated by server to all connected and listening clients.

That data should not been stored in Mongo Collection but is only available as a volatile dataset or object.

There are some packages doing those kinds like [YookanOO/streamy](https://github.com/YuukanOO/streamy) but I do not know if this is the right technical way.

I created an example with a Meteor Local Client Collection at meteorpad:

[Sample_Publish_to_Local-Collection](http://meteorpad.com/pad/jYDG3wjryGc6DHXa6/Sample_Publish_to_Local-Collection)

Q: What is the right decision? Local Collections or a library like [Yookan:Streamy](https://github.com/YuukanOO/streamy)?

Comment: This is an [aligned thread at Meteor Forum](https://forums.meteor.com/t/meteor-and-the-internet-of-things-iot-whats-best-to-use-collection-meteor-streams-streamy/792/5)

Answer (score 0):

I would go with what you are already doing. Publish/subscribe with this.ready/this.changed/this.added etc.

Comment: Hi Adnan, I created another meteorpad followed guide by [DiscoverMeteor template level descriptions](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/template-level-subscriptions/)  
http://meteorpad.com/pad/Zq4QdMW84rKGersFH/Sample_Publish_to_Local-Collection_Reactive_way

So this should fit?

Comment: Sorry but I don't see much difference. You have added some more checks for isReady in the second one, I see.

Comment: HI Adnan, yes you are right, it was just my question if that kind of `isReady()` is what you had implied in your first comment. So, thanks for your feedback.